# No connection established with Cloud Functions and Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having issues with connecting to my firestore DB from a cloud function.

I get the below error:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "test"
>  Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
>      at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:174:52)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:340:141)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:303:181)
>      at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:114:27)
>      at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:153:22)
>      at Http2CallStream.endCall (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:140:18)
>      at Http2CallStream.cancelWithStatus (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:430:14)
>      at ChannelImplementation.tryPick (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:214:32)
>      at Object.updateState (/Users/michael/project/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:82:26) {
>    code: 14,
>    details: 'No connection established',
>    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
>  }
```

The service account credentials are pointed to by the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

This is my functions code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
let db = admin.firestore();

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

      db.collection("users").doc("test").set({
          'name': 'Michael'
      }).then(ref => {
          res.send(ref.id);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)  
        res.status(500).send(err);
      })

});
```

... and these are my dependencies in my `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

I've seen there are more people facing similar issues, they say I should upgrade to the latest version of the firebase-functions and firebase-admin, but in my case they are up to date. Ive also deleted `node_modules/` and re-installed it again but the issue persists.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't need the googleapis dependency.  Try removing it.

Comment: Also note that `set()` doesn't yield a snapshot.  Calling `snap.data()` will fail. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set

Comment: Edited my sample code. I need googleapis for something else, but still, tried removing it and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Have you ever set an environment variable called `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST`?

If that environment variable is set, the firebase admin SDK will try to connect to the emulator instead of the firestore, and if you haven't started the emulator, the `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established` will occur.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore?hl=en

Comment: this was really the issue I had last week...; `refreshenv` in win did not work in cmd; I had to restart and my script started to work again

Comment: I had set the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST in my .zshrc to always point to local emulator (so I won't accidentally modify production)... when I need to go to production directly, I forgot about this fact... your answer helped me... thank you.